# How to concatenate strings in sql server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to concatenate strings but it doesn't seem to work. Can somebody tell me what is wrong with the code below?

```
declare @x varchar = 'a';

SET @x += 's'

SET @x = @x + 'z'

SET @x = concat('x','y')

SELECT @x;
```

None of the above methods worked. I am getting the output as 'x'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per Aaron Bertrand's article here:

https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length

...you should not be declaring `VARCHAR` without a length.

> The problem is, if you don't define a length, SQL Server will assign
>   one for you, and it may not be as wide as you expect.  In some
>   scenarios, it will be 1 (yes, that is the number one, not a typo), and
>   in others it will be 30.

The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql) are quite clear in this as well:

> **varchar [ ( n | max ) ]**
>   When n is not specified in a data definition or variable declaration
>   statement, the default length is 1. When n is not specified when using
>   the CAST and CONVERT functions, the default length is 30.

This will work fine:

```
declare @x varchar(10) = 'a';

SET @x += 's'

SET @x = @x + 'z'

SET @x = concat('x','y')

SELECT @x;
```

Answer (score 3):

You need a length when you declare `varchar()`.  Otherwise, it is only one character long:

```
declare @x varchar(255) = 'a';
```

Once the variable is big enough to store the value, the rest of the code should work.

Answer (score 3):

You need to tell sql the length of your varchar. In most cases sql treat varchar as varchar(1)

```
declare @x varchar(10) = 'a';
SET @x += 's'
SET @x = @x + 'z'

SET @x = concat('x','y')

SELECT @x;
```

Answer (score 2):

The code below will work, remember you need to declare strings long enough to contain the result.

```
declare @a varchar(100)
declare @b varchar(100)

set @a = 'This should ';
set @b = 'work';
select @a + @b
```

If you have shorter strings like this:

```
declare @a varchar(4)
declare @b varchar(4)

set @a = 'This should ';
set @b = 'work';
select @a + @b
```

You'll end up with the result:

```
'Thiswork'
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare your VARCHAR with a length, try changing it to VARCHAR(20) and see what happens.

Declaring VARCHAR without a length results in Length being 1.